# Listing the dependencies of a shared library in Solaris

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am converting a set of static libraries to shared libraries and was able to create the shared libraries successfully. The problem is with the exe's because linking with static library can have unresolved symbols in the library but that is not the case with shared libraries. All the symbols in the shared library should get resolved.

Example:
PROG1 calls LIB1.a calls LIB2.a
Now the make file of PROG1 need not have LIB2.a as PROG1 calls to LIB1.a do not result in calling LIB2.a .So some LIB2.a symbols in LIB1.a can remain unresolved.

After conversion 
Both LIB1.so and LIB2.so have to be included in the makefile of PROG1. Including LIB2.so resolves few linkage issues of LIB1.so but new issues appear due to inclusion of LIB2.so(as it may be depend on LIB3.so)

SO is there any way to find out the all the dependent libraries of a shared library?
I tried using ldd but it prints nothing.

Please let me know if my analysis is wrong.

Comment: ldd output shows nothing?  It has to depend at least on libc.  Please add the output of ldd for all three libraries you mentioned.

Comment: ruby% ls -ltr libStorage.so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 suda dvlpmnt       20 May 23 03:20 libStorage.so -> libStorage.so.1
ruby% ls -ltr libStorage.so.1
-rwxrwxr-x   1 asik  dvlpmnt  5705636 Jun  6 03:43 libStorage.so.1
ruby% ldd libStorage.so
ruby%

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly personal opinion, but I think you should link your shared libraries so that you get an error for unresolved symbols (with `-z defs`). That means you sort out each library independently and don't get any nasty surprises at link time.

Of course, this only works if your libraries are clean and don't contain recursive dependencies (which are probably a bad thing anyway) and you aren't trying to do dynamic loading where you can load any of `impl_1.so`, `impl_2.so` or `impl3_.so` to provide code for a client `client.so` at runtime. But it works well if all you have are link time dependencies.

Indeed, if you don't do this, and are using `ld` rather than `cc` to do the linking,, you'll get pretty much what you're seeing - no dependencies, and errors at linktime